My subdirectories keep redirecting to homepage (WordPress)
My subdirectories keep redirecting to homepage (WordPress).
I already checked my .htaccess and wp-config.php but not sure what is actually wrong. My WordPress is hosted on AWS LightSail and DB on Maria DB. Everything seem good on the DB and Server.


Permalinks Settings: check whether your permalinks settings in WordPress are correctly configured or not. Go to Settings > Permalinks choose a required permalink structure (common as Post name) and save changes. Sometimes redirect issues can be fixed by resetting permalinks.

Even if you've mentioned you've checked .htaccess, it's better to recheck the .htaccess file. And Make sure it's properly configured for WordPress. Below is a standard WordPress .htaccess configuration:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


Sometimes, some faulty plugins or themes can cause redirects. So temporarily deactivate all plugins and switch to a default WordPress theme (like Twenty Twenty-One) to see if the issue is resolved or not, if it's resolved reactivate each plugin/theme one by one until you find the one causing the issue.

You can check by WordPress debugging to see if any errors are being thrown it might indicate the source of the redirect. You can do this by adding the following lines to your wp-config.php file:

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );


Make sure there are no conflicting configurations on your AWS LightSail server that might be causing the redirects. Check your server's virtual host configuration and any other relevant server settings also.

Recheck that the WordPress settings in the database (specifically URL and home in the wp_options table) are correct.

If you're using any caching plugins or server-side caching, clear the cache to make sure that it's not causing the redirection.


